# PHP considers null is equal to zero

Tags: php, null

In PHP, `($myvariable==0)`
When $myvariable is zero, the value of the expression is true; when $myvariable is null, the value of this expression is also true. How can I exclude the second case? I mean I want the expression to be true only when $myvariable is zero. Of course I can write

```
($myvariable != null && $myvariable == 0)
```

But is there other elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
$myvariable === 0
```

read more about [comparison operators](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Comment: Unless $myvariable is a float in which case $myvariable === floatval(0)

Answer (score 17):

You hint at a deep question: when should an expression be true?

Below, I will explain *why* what you are doing isn't working and *how* to fix it.

In many languages `null`, `0`, and the empty string (`""`) all evaluate to false, this can make `if` statements quite succinct and intuitive, but `null`, `0`, and `""` are also all of different types. How should they be compared?

[This page](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) tells us that if we have two variables being compared, then the variables are converted as follows (exiting the table at the first match)

```
Type of First  Type of Second   Then
null/string    string           Convert NULL to "", numerical/lexical comparison
bool/null      anything         Convert to bool, FALSE < TRUE
```

So you are comparing a null versus a number. Therefore, both the null and the number are converted to boolean. [This page](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) tells us that in such a conversion both `null` and `0` are considered `FALSE`.

Your expression now reads, `false==false`, which, of course, is true.

But not what you want.

[This page](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) provides a list of PHP's comparison operators.

```
Example   Name                Result
$a ==  $b  Equal              TRUE if $a equals $b after type juggling.
$a === $b  Identical          TRUE if $a equals $b, AND they are of the same type.
$a !=  $b  Not equal          TRUE if $a not equals $b after type juggling.
$a <>  $b  Not equal          TRUE if $a not equals $b after type juggling.
$a !== $b  Not identical      TRUE if $a not equals $b, or they are not of the same type.
$a  <  $b  Less than          TRUE if $a is strictly less than $b.
$a  >  $b  Greater than       TRUE if $a is strictly greater than $b.
$a <=  $b  Less than/equal    TRUE if $a is less than or equal to $b.
$a >=  $b  Greater than/equal TRUE if $a is greater than or equal to $b.
```

The first comparator is the comparison you are using now. Note that it performs the conversions I mentioned earlier.

Using the second comparator will fix your problem. Since a null and a number are not of the same type, the `===` comparison will return false, rather than performing type conversion as the `==` operator would.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

To identify as null or zero by:

- `is_int($var)` if a variable is a number or a numeric string. To identify Zero, use `is_numeric($var)` is also the solution or use `$var === 0`
- `is_null($var)` if a variable is NULL

Answer (score 5):

Try `($myvariable === 0)` which will not perform type coercion.

Answer (score 4):

Use the php function [is_null( )](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function along with the `===` operator. `!==` also works the way you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

The second solution wouldn't work either. The [`===` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your zero could be a string, you should also considere checking the "zero string"

```
($myvariable === 0 || $myvariable === '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

I hade faced a similar issue in one of my projects, with a minor difference that I was also using the values ZERO as a valid value for my condition. here's how I solved it using simple logic to separate NULL from zero and other values.

```
    if (gettype($company_id) === 'NULL') {
        $company = Company::where('id', Auth::user()->company_id)->first();
    } else {
        $company = Company::where('id', $company_id)->first();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myvariable===0


$a === $b
```

Identical TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type

Answer (score 0):

There's an [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-null.php) function, but this will just replace your `$myvariable!=null`

Answer (score -2):

For my case i found this soulution and it works for me :

```
if ($myvariable === NULL) {
    codehere...
}
```

Comment: If doing like this then you should use triple equal signs: `===`