# How can PHP 5.3 think 0 is null?

Tags: php

I wrote a simple test:

```
$test = null;
if ($test == null) print 'is null';
else print 'not null';
```

This prints out: "is null". Problem is, I changed it to this:

```
$test = 0;
if ($test == null) print 'is null';
else print 'not null';
```

And it still prints out null? Why?

Comment: 0 is null in PHP: indepth answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096097/1352271

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: You are using a loose type unspecific comparison, in that case 0 will equal null.

Comment: You may want to read [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [type comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: Because of == and === are different operators. This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `is_null` function

```
is_null($test)
```

#### Test

```
$test = 0;
if (is_null($test)) print 'is null';
else print 'not null';

// Return not null
```

Comment: Someone explain to me why downvoted? My answer isnt useful? `is_null` function totaly right return! Please leave comment who downvoted users

Comment: Some claim `is_null` peforms less well over a type specific comparison like `0 === null` but personally I don't think that would be a reason to downvote an answer, even if it's true.

Comment: while you are giving a solution to the question, you are not "answering" it. Question wants to know "HOW" php thinks 0 is null, not how to circumvent that.

Comment: @Oerd Answered in comments `0 is null in PHP`. I just give you another solution. Read SO Document http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Bora: 0 is *NOT* null in PHP, it *evaulates* to null in a boolean expression, which is more or less different than being null (depending on who you ask)

Comment: `Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative`

Comment: @Bora: Jack's answer has given it... fwiw, I have not downvoted this answer (yours) I respect you taking the time to write these lines and share your knowledge. There are people who are really tight about this, they are just not the norm in the php community (and it's a pity imho)

Answer (score 3):

That's because PHP performs a [loose comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) when you use `==`, i.e. it will attempt to coerce one of the operands into the type of the other if they're not the same.

For example:

```
array() == false
null == ''
0 == '0'
```

To compare the value *and* type together you need the `===` (triple equals operator), e.g.

```
if (null === 0) {
    // this can never happen
}
```

This be the burden of using a dynamically typed language :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP treats `0` as `NULL`.

To check if a value is `NULL`, you can either use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/is_null) function or use `===` in your conditional statement:

```
$test = 0;
if ($test === null) print 'is null';
else print 'not null';
```

See a [demo](http://ideone.com/bkLnVs) here.

Refer to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/operators.comparison) for more information.